# Angular 2 image not refreshing with Zone run

Tags: image, angular, refresh

I'm creating an image from an external source (a qrcode on a java ee server). When my Angular2 app updates the data for the image, everything gets updated on the server but the resulting image is not refreshed in the angular app. I'm currently doing a zone.run but it doesn't seem to refresh the image, Everything is fine if the entire page gets refreshed (eg. if I place a location.reload). Anybody no how to properly refresh an image from an external source?

template has this:

```
     <img [src]=url />
```

component has this:

```
        this.zone.run(()=>{
            this.url = QRURL + this.selectedProduct.id;
        });
```

QRURL is a constant that contains the server's url that executes the generation of the image.

Comment: You shouldn't need to run zone on your own. It's either a cache problem or maybe something about the syntax (`<img [src]=url />` should be `<img [src]="url" />`. Please give some code around the `this.zone.run`, we need more context.

Comment: If it's a cache problem, try to change your URL to : `this.url = QRURL + this.selectedProduct.id + '?' + new Date().getTime();`. This way, your browser won't hit some cache (because of timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

The quotes didn't fix it, but Maxime's 2nd comment did. My constant alread y had a query string, so I just added the date stuff as another parameter on it, and that did the trick and I was able to strip off the zone.run. The final variable looked like this:

```
        this.url = QRURL + this.selectedProduct.id + '&date=' + new Date().getTime();
```

Thanks!